# jquery-ui: Dialog not opened at vertical center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jquery ui dialog which is defined as this:

```
$('#processPosition').dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        open: function ()
        {           
            dialogProps.originalContent = $("#processPosition").html(),
            dialogProps.type = $(this).data('type');

            $('#' + dialogProps.type).appendTo($(this));
            $('#rejectPosition').appendTo($(this));
            $("#processPosition .template").removeClass("template");
        },
        show : "blind",
        modal : true,
        resizable : false,
        scrollbar : false
    });
```

This is how i open it:

```
$('#processOrderPosition').dialog({width: 800})
                          .dialog('option', 'position', 'center')
                          .dialog("open");
```

This is the only css of the template class:

```
.template
{
    display: none;
}
```

Html template `div`s:

```
<div id="SAP-flst-Dialog" class="template">
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="rejectOrderPosition" class="template">
    <h4>second Header</h4>
    <span>Some more Text</span>
</div>
```

I also tried to set the position attribute after opening it, but with no effect. In the dev tools of my browser i can see, that a `div` is generated by jquery and this div has a wrong value for the css `top` attribute. The `div` has the following classes: `ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable`

What is causing the wrong top value?

Comment: Add your html as well

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/c85fo36u/6

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#processPosition').dialog({
  autoOpen : false,
  open: function ()
  {           
      dialogProps.originalContent = $("#processPosition").html(),
      dialogProps.type = $(this).data('type');
      $('#' + dialogProps.type).appendTo($(this));
      $('#rejectPosition').appendTo($(this));
      $("#processPosition .template").removeClass("template");
  },
  show : "blind",
  modal : true,
  resizable : false,
  scrollbar : false
});
```

$('#processPosition').dialog().dialog("open");

})

Look at this fiddle, i have added border to div to see that is centered.